# context KeyError in django templateTag

Tags: python, django, django-templates

My app's templatetag code is throwing a KeyError for a missing key (`page`) in the context variable.  In my template, I do not refer to context variables with context.variableKeyName, I just refer to variableKeyName (e.g. `{% if is_paginated %}`).  And in my template, I can refer to the key `page` without any exceptions.

How should I get the context with the keys it needs into my templatetag?

---

Here are the details:

I am using django-profiles to return a list of some profiles:

```
url(r'^profiles/$', 'profiles.views.profile_list', 
kwargs={ 'paginate_by':10 }, 
name='profiles_profile_detail'),
```

which calls this bit of code here:
[https://bitbucket.org/ubernostrum/django-profiles..](https://bitbucket.org/ubernostrum/django-profiles/src/c21962558420/profiles/views.py#cl-332)

In my template, I test `{% if is_paginated %}` before I call a templatetag:

```
{% if is_paginated %}{% load paginator %}{% paginator 3 %}{% endif %}
```

( I am using a templatetag inspired from [http://www.tummy.com/.../django-pagination/](http://www.tummy.com/Community/Articles/django-pagination/) updated for django 1.3 http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2680/ )

But this leads to the KeyError for 'paged'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation (comments in the class) of http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2680/ says:

> Required context variables: paged: The Paginator.page() instance.

It is also used in the template tag:

```
paged = context['paged']
```

You need to provide this context variable for this template tag to work. I think your best bet is to copy the code of  `profiles.views.profile_list` view and add this context variable. It's unfortunately still a function-based view - otherwise extending it would have been a lot cleanier and easier.

Comment: Thanks Simeon. Isn't the context implicit in my template (since page & is_paginated can be referenced without error?).  I assumed the same implicit context would pass to the templatetag.  If I understand your response correctly, I need to explicitly set either context or the paged variable it in the view code?

Answer (score 0):

the right way to code is:

```
{% paginator v 3 %}
```

`v` - variable that contains the db items